# Show that if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_E|f_n|=\int_E|f|$ then $\int_E|f-f_n|\rightarrow 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of integrable functions on $E$ for which $f_n$ converges to $f$ a.e. on $E$, and $f$ is integrable over $E$. Show that if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_E|f_n|=\int_E|f|$ then $\int_E|f-f_n|\rightarrow 0$.

So I feel like this should be really obvious, but I'm having a hard time proving it. I'd appreciate some advice! The details are what get me!

Comment: not obvious, iirc. go through proof of dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: You may want to check [the answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3423805/9340) in the link.