# Sufficient conditions for $\mathscr{L}^p$ convergence?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $p \in [1,\infty)$, $f,f_1,f_2,...\in \mathscr{L}^1(X,\mathscr{A},\mu, \mathbb{R})$ are all nonnegative functions, such that ${f_n}\rightarrow f$ a.e. It is known that this is not sufficient to guarantee that $\lim_n ||f_n-f||_p=0$. If I add the condition $\lim_n ||f_n||_p=||f||_p$, does it imply $\lim_n ||f_n-f||_p=0$ now? This seems intuitively appealing but I am not able to prove (or disprove) it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/577946/prove-that-int-e-f-n-f-to0-iff-lim-limits-n-to-infty-int-ef-n-int-ef

Comment: @That actually does not answerer the question since 
$|f+f_n|^p \leq |f|^p + |f_n|^p$ is false for general $p$, that only works for $p=1$.